# batch file to Copy FOLDER with newest time stamp from network drive to local

Tags: batch-file

I need to write a batch file to copy a folder, not file, from a network drive, that has been the most recently updated, to my local machine.

This is what I have, but it cannot find anything to copy because I want to copy a folder, not a file.

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir S:\Development\NightlyBuilds /B /A-D /O-D') do copy "%%a" U:\PWJ
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `copy`, you can use `xcopy`. Use the `/s` flag to copy recursively. Make sure to terminate your PWJ folder with a `\` to indicate that the destination is a folder. You can also use robocopy. It's a lot more robust. You can look up its parameters in `robocopy /?`.

Answer (score 0):

You were using the wrong options for FOR and DIR commands, performing a copy for every file in date newest to oldest.

```bat
@ECHO OFF

(SET SrcDir=S:\Development\NightlyBuilds)
(SET DstDir=U:\PWJ)

IF NOT EXIST "%SrcDir%\" EXIT/B
IF NOT EXIST "U:\PWJ\" EXIT/B
IF /I NOT "%CD%"=="%SrcDir%" PushD "%SrcDir%"

FOR /F "DELIMS=" %%A IN ('DIR/B/AD-L/OD *') DO SET Latest="%%A"
ROBOCOPY %Latest% "%DstDir%\%Latest%" /E

EXIT/B
```